How to use AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer previously created in EKS
I have created resources using CloudFormation, including:

AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
AWS::Route53::RecordSet (pointing to the loadbalancer)

Is it possible to use this previously created LB for pods created in EKS? I'm only seeing info related to create an aws-load-balancer-controller directly in the cluster but I'd like to keep the resources in cloudformation.

Well actually there is an open issue to support this feature natively in ALBC.
But in the meanwhile you can you use a workaround with TargetGroupBinding if you want to manage an entire ingress resource with an existing load balancer.
This is a custom resource that expose pods using existing ALB TargetGroup and also NLB TargetGroup.

Thanks Saifeddine. I thought I should use only TargetGroupBinding to expose it but AWS support said the aws-load-balancer-controller is also required, the documentation was not very clear about it.
